# Ambient Oclusion Diffuse bake errors

Tags: baking

I made a low poly version of this object and the bake was perfect, but now I'm doing the higher poly version and the bake has this imperfection.

Rendered:
[image]

Baked texture:
[image]

It has that imperfection on top, as you can see. Why this happens?

Comment: First things I would check:
 - is the normal map is in non-color Color Space, (especially sometimes you can change it only after you save the image)
 - your baked map is connected to a node from Vector->Normal Map, and then this node to normal slot in the shader node. On top of that, if Vector->Normal Map node is set to use Tangent Space
 - your models faces shading (flat/smooth) is the same as at the moment of baking

Comment: This is happening to a baked color (diffuse) map, not a normal map. The issue is in the color. The baked map is simply connected via image texture nod to BSDF.